# Why can't use only one specific city in google places api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to search addresses only in Amsterdam (The Netherlands), I tried it with bounds, adding &input=amsterdam to the string but it stil shows more cities

The html:

```
<input id="autocomplete" name=origin type=text placeholder=Vertreklocatie class="autocomplete">
```

JS

```
function initialize() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete');

    var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng( 52.318274,4.728856 );
    var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng( 52.431157,5.068373 );
    var hyderabadBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );

    var options = {
      bounds: hyderabadBounds,
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'nl'},
      types: ['address']  
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], options); 
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Is there an option to search only in one city?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dozZwZ